# How to add an abstract layer to manage settings of multiple pom's

Tags: maven

I have like 10 maven projects(and behind them Jenkins jobs) which have quite the same configuration. They all have a parent, call it `ancient`.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ancient</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>child_10</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<properties >
    <reports.to.keep>20</reports.to.keep>
</properties>
```

Now I don't want to add the properties which are the same for all those members, so I created a `parent` for all my 10 children:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ancient</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<properties >
    <reports.to.keep>20</reports.to.keep>
</properties>
```

I adapted the children to point to that one.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
```

Thats for the concept. Now I got the problem that I can not deploy my parent to my repository, as it always like wants to build whats configured in the `ancient`.

I am quite new to Maven: is this even possible? Or is there an other way to manage multiple maven projects with inheritance?

Problem is that ancient is configured so that I can not use `deploy` or `deploy-file` as they are configured to deploy something else. I also want them configured like that for my child-projects.

Comment: Is your ancient is also a aggregator? By 10 jobs do you mean Jenkins (CI) jobs?

Comment: Would it be possible to create a job with a different pom to deploy the `parent-pom` ?

Comment: Aggregator means, a maven project with a modules section, that has other maven projects as modules. As far as I know jobs is not a term for maven, it is used for CI servers. If you mean CI jobs (and Jenkins), check https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin .

Comment: @SilverShroud It is not an Aggregator. I am confusing Jobs and Projects as one job on Jenkins builds one maven project. I need that hierarchy on maven projects, as there are e.g site-deployments and uploads to a queue from another system triggered.